# How to calculate word co-occurence

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string of characters of length 50 say representing a sequence `abbcda....` for alphabets taken from the set `A={a,b,c,d}`.

I want to calculate how many times `b` is followed by another `b` (n-grams) where n=2.

Similarly, how many times a particular character is repeated thrice n=3 consecutively, say in the input string `abbbcbbb` etc so here the number of times `b` occurs in a sequence of 3 letters is 2.

Comment: 5 answers and 1 up-vote!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the number of non-overlapping 2-grams you can use

```
numel(regexp(str, 'b{2}'))
```

and for 3-grams

```
numel(regexp(str, 'b{3}'))
```

to count overlapping 2-grams use positive lookahead

```
numel(regexp(str, '(b)(?=b{1})'))
```

and for overlapping `n`-grams

```
numel(regexp(str, ['(b)(?=b{' num2str(n-1) '})']))
```

**EDIT**
In order to find number of occurrences of an arbitrary sequence use the first element in first parenthesis and the rest after equality sign, to find `ba` use

```
numel(regexp(str, '(b)(?=a)'))
```

to find `bda` use

```
numel(regexp(str, '(b)(?=da)'))
```

Comment: For `str = 'abbbcbbbbdbbabbb'` and `n = 2` this will count 5. I am actually unsure if this is wanted by the OP.

Comment: @OlegKomarov true, depends if you are looking for overlapping matches or not. I updated the answer and I think the OP is looking for overlapping matches.

Comment: Thank you.I am also interested to know that if it is possible to find consecutive dissimilar letters like "ab" that is b followed by a. Then in the numel(regexp(str, ['(b)(?=b{' num2str(n-1) '})'])) what do I have to modify?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this piece of code that uses `ismember` ([doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)).

```
%generate string (50 char, 'a' to 'd') 
str = char(floor(97 + (101-97).*rand(1,50)))

%digram case
index_digram = ismember(str, 'aa');

%trigram case
index_trigram = ismember(str, 'aaa');
```

**EDIT**

Probabilities can be computed with

```
proba = sum(index_digram)/length(index_digram);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.Is there a way to find out the probabilities as well?How can the probabilities be calculated?

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using? It doesn't seem to work on R2007a

Comment: strange - R2012b - can't find an online help for ismember 2007a. Please see the edit for probabilities.

Comment: Than you,it is easier to follow yours.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the proposal by Magla:

```
str = 'abcdabbcdaabbbabbbb'; % for example
index_single = ismember(str, 'b');
index_digram = index_single(1:end-1)&index_single(2:end);
index_trigram = index_single(1:end-2)&index_single(2:end-1)&index_single(3:end);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will find all n-grams and count them:

```
numberOfGrams = 5;
s = char(floor(rand(1,1000)*4)+double('a'));
ngrams = cell(1);
for n = 2:numberOfGrams
    strLength = size(s,2)-n+1;
    indices = repmat((1:strLength)',1,n)+repmat(1:n,strLength,1)-1;
    grams = s(indices);
    gramNumbers = (double(grams)-double('a'))*((ones(1,n)*n).^(0:n-1))';
    [uniqueGrams, gramInd] = unique(gramNumbers);
    count=hist(gramNumbers,uniqueGrams);
    ngrams(n) = {struct('gram',grams(gramInd,:),'count',count)};
end
```

edit:

the result will be:

```
ngrams{n}.gram       %a list of all n letter sequences in the string
ngrams{n}.count(x)   %the number of times the sequence ngrams{n}.gram(x) appears
```

Comment: Thank you,but will this find something like this that count b followed by an a?

Comment: well, yes, it will count the number of occurrences of any n-letter 'word'.